# T-SQL: Как распарсить такую XML

Tags: xml, sql-server, xmlparser

Имеем XML:

```
<status>
  <message id="0F051363" />
  <state code="DELIVERED" date="02.09.2016 00:00:00">Message has been delivered</state>
</status>
```

Пробую так:

```
select top 100 ms.[stat].value('(status/message id/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

Ошибка:

```
XQuery [dbo.Statuses.stat.value()]: Syntax error near '[', expected a step expression.
```

Как правильно ее распарсить?

Спасибо

Comment: `[stat].value('(/status/message/@id)[1]', 'char(10)')` так запросить id, `[stat].value('(/status/state/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')` так текст. тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/extract-value-of-attribute-node-via-xpath ещё примеры

Comment: Спасибо! 
Сработал вариант [stat].value('(/status/message/@id)[1]', 'char(10)'
Напишите ответ к вопросу, пожалуйста, и я его закрою.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Атрибуты запрашиваются так  `[stat].value('(/status/message/@id)[1]', 'char(10)')`

Текст запрашивается  так `[stat].value('(/status/state/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')`

Пару слов о типах. Если `varchar(n)` - вернёт "правильную строку". `char(n)` - дополнит недостающие символы пробелами. Если `int` то в случае ошибки конвертирование в число  - даст ошибку.

Как на mssql проверить быстро:

```
select 
[stat].query('/status/message'),
[stat].value('(/status/state/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from
(select 
cast(
'<status>
  <message id="0F051363" />
  <state code="DELIVERED" date="02.09.2016 00:00:00">Message has been delivered</state>
</status>' as xml) stat) t
```

Вариант проще

```
declare @x xml 
set @x = '<a>1</a>'
select @x.value('(/a/text())[1]','int')
```

Если хотите запросить ветку - использовать `[stat].query('/status/message')`

Полезные ссылки [so-En](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835891/extract-value-of-attribute-node-via-xpath) [msdn-примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms256086%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)